# CloudWatch show undefined in console.log on object

Tags: javascript, amazon-cloudwatch

I have this:

```
console.log('pictures', pictures);
console.log('pictures.carnetFront', pictures.carnetFront);
```

In CloudWatch I got:

```
INFO    pictures { pictures: { carnetFront: 'aaaa', carnetBack: 'BB', selfie: 'CC' } }
INFO    pictures.carnetFront undefined
```

Why? I don't get it

[image]

Comment: I guess it should be `pictures.pictures.carnetFront` which would give you `aaaa` in console.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it should be `pictures.pictures.carnetFront`?